# Cheap or DIY Keyboard Overlays?

Tags: keyboard

I am in charge to furnish a class with keyboards that have colored keys for special functions. It's for kids in their free time to learn video cutting and editing (mainly on [Final Cut Pro](http://www.apple.com/de/finalcutstudio/finalcutpro/)).

Now, these [Logic Keyboards](http://www.logickeyboard.com/shop/Euro/apple-final-cut-1629p.html) or [Overlays](http://www.kbcovers.com/servlet/Categories?category=Final+Cut) already exist, but are fairly expensive, and as you can imagine, there is not much money in such free time projects.

Does anyone know of cheaper/simpler solutions ?

We are quite a handful of helpers with different handcraft skills, so we are going to try this on our own if we do not find a buyable solution. The results will of course be on display here, if not considered off-topic.

No, the [Optimus Maximus](http://www.thinkgeek.com/computing/input/9836/) is not a solution :)

Comment: The kbcovers.com site looks like a good option -- is 29$ really too expensive?

Comment: @sqook: they are not that easy to get in europe :(

Comment: What is your price range and location?

Comment: @squook - I'd agree with you for one keyboard, but with multiple kids, I think $300 for 10 keyboards is money better spent on other educational materials.

Comment: I sooo agree with that "fairly expensive" note - how come a regular cheap keyboard with some colored keys marked for Adobe Premiere or Avid (FC is what? ;p) costs about 5-6 times as much? Anyhow, just spray-paint them - forces everyone to learn the alfa-numeric keys without looking anyway... ^^

Answer (score 3):

This is the cheapest thing I could find:

http://www.4keyboard.com/apple-final-cut-keyboard-stickers-p-176.html

Comment: I bought them, those are not bad. But not the kicker yet.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [this guy](http://isometricland.com/keyboard/keyboard.php) may have put together something that'll do in a pinch.  It looks like people have added schemes for non-game-related overlays, so I'd imagine you'd be able to use it for your purpose.

(I haven't used them, but it looks promising.)

Comment: this is an excellent finding, also for unrelated stuff !

Comment: "Sorry, the GeoCities web site you were trying to reach is no longer available." - very unfortunate !

Comment: Yahoo pulled the plug on GeoCities, but it looks like the page still lives!  Updated the link in the post.

Comment: Website does not exist anymore...

Comment: There may be helpful links in the wayback archive for the page: http://web.archive.org/web/20091022112945/http://www.isometricland.com/keyboard/keyboard.php

Answer (score 2):

In the good old days, PC gaming magazines would print a double A4 card printed sheet designed to fold out & fit over standard keyboards for popular games. Not so much an overlay as a keyboard attached cheat sheet. Kind of like the old TI-99 overlays.

Not an ideal solution but both cheap and simple!